# Socketplane and Docker : How to connect 2 (or more) physical hosts with each others

Tags: network-programming, docker, consul

I used to work with [Weave](https://github.com/zettio/weave) for docker networking concerns between 2 or more hosts. 
I saw that Docker [bought](http://thenewstack.io/docker-acquires-sdn-technology-startup-socketplane-io/), few days ago, [SocketPlane](https://github.com/socketplane/socketplane).
Docker's goal seems to integrate SocketPlane as networking feature.

I read many times the documentation (which is not very rich for now) but I haven't see how to connect two physical hosts across the network.

I have seen that a new cluster feature had been added in the last month ([issue #69](https://github.com/socketplane/socketplane/issues/69)) but i found no documentation about it.

**I would like to know if anybody already managed to connect 2 physical hosts or more in a same docker network (containers speaking across hosts) using SocketPlane**

There's another feature in socketplane on which I can't find documentation. It is about Consul integration.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since my message, I managed to add server in cluster but containers from different servers can't see each others.
I created an issue on socketplane's github and it appears to be a bug that is going to be resolved soon.
[Issue #149](https://github.com/socketplane/socketplane/issues/149)